# Create page in confluence using powershell

Tags: powershell, confluence

When i am creating confluence paging using below powershell code, it works for smaller html codes but word documents converted to HTML throws error.

[image]

Here is the powershell code

```
$ConfluenceURL = "https://wiki-test.company.com/confluence/rest/api/content"
$cred = Get-Credential
$BODYVALUE=Get-Content 'C:\Users\test.html'



 $Headers = @{'Authorization' = "Basic "+[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(($cred.UserName+":"+[System.Runtime.InteropServices.marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([System.Runtime.InteropServices.marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($cred.Password)) )))
'X-Atlassian-Token' = 'nocheck'
}
$pageTitle = "convert1"
$space = "DEMO"
$body =
"{
`"type`":`"page`",
`"title`":`"$pageTitle`",
`"space`": {`"key`":`"$space`"},
`"body`":{
`"storage`":{
`"representation`":`"storage`",
`"value`":`"<p>$BODYVALUE</p>`"
}
}
}"
Invoke-WebRequest -Method POST -Headers $Headers -Uri $ConfluenceURL -Body $body -ContentType "application/json" | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Comment: You might want to [use a here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7#here-strings) for that `$body` variable

Comment: Check if Confluence or web server has an error log that describes with more details what's the problem.